# Security risk(s) in running bitcoin core full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, full-node, wallet-security

What are the security risks posed by running a full node bitcoin core client? On a typical system, port 8333 is open and all other nodes can actually 'see' my machine and sites like https://bitnodes.earn.com/ can verify the connection.

How can the risks be mitigated? (I'm on Windows)

Comment: The risk of running a full node (as opposed to using different wallet software/service), or the risk of opening up a port (as opposed to leaving it closed, but still running Bitcoin Core)?

Answer (score 2):

1) None. Don't open the port (default).

2) None required. 
Obviously you don't want to download Bitcoin Core binary from random sites, you want validate it, etc. as per bitcoincore.org's instructions.